# Using UIImagePickerController with web data source

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it possible to pick images from web using UIImagePickerController or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download images from the web to the cache directory and then show them in your UIImagePickerController, I guess.

Comment: No, there is way to do it without downloading them, but i don't know how

Comment: @TimurMustafaev How do you know there's a way to do it, if you don't know what it is?  (I'm not positive there isn't one, but my first thought is to agree with BillWilson's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you will not be able to use the UIImagePickerController to select images from anything but the built-in Apple provided image sources. i.e. camera, camera roll, photo library.

There are a few Open Source image pickers out there, a quick search on GitHub brought this one up [JPImagePickerController](https://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController)